# Can't generate javadoc for file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

As seen from the image below. Generating javadoc via tools->generate javadoc produces the following window. I cannot however press ok as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have not entered a location for the Output Directory, in the middle of that dialog menu. It is directly above the slider for the javadoc package visibility.